# undefined reference to `krb5_kt_free_entry'

Tags: c++, gcc, ssl

I understand that the order of libraries in gcc matters , but how do i figure out which libraries should be out first since I dont know which depends on which ?

I keep getting errors related to ssl library. Few of them are below

```
/usr/lib/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
(.text+0x20b9): undefined reference to `krb5_kt_default'
/usr/lib/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
(.text+0x2119): undefined reference to `krb5_kt_get_entry'
/usr/lib/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
(.text+0x218f): undefined reference to `krb5_decrypt_tkt_part'
/usr/lib/libssl.a(kssl.o): In function `kssl_sget_tkt':
(.text+0x21b5): undefined reference to `krb5_kt_free_entry'
```

I've used this order in the makefile :

```
LIBS   = -lstdc++ -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
```

Please could someone guide how do i get rid of these undefined references ? Do I really need krb5 library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it looks like you may need to add `-lkrb5` to the list of libraries. Put it before `-lssl`.

Comment: I tried doing this, doesn't work. Gives me the same error. Is -ldl in the correct position ?

Comment: `-ldl` just provides `dlopen` and related functions, so it isn't relevant to your error message.

Comment: Any idea what libraries should be included for mysql client? I'm just modifying a makefile to be able to connect to myql server.

Comment: I believe if libssl needs symbols in libkrb5 then -lkbr5 needs to come *after* -lssl.

Comment: I tried doing this and I think krb5 needs something else. Because it gives me these errors --- /usr/lib/libkrb5.a(hostaddr.o): In function `krb5_os_hostaddr':
(.text+0x222): undefined reference to `krb5int_freeaddrinfo'

Comment: Have you tried installing and linking to the dynamic libraries (`.so`)?

Comment: I akready have them installed . How do I link them in make file ?

Comment: still doesnt work. the application works as a standalone utility with this LIBS   = -lstdc++ -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lssl -lcrypto    but doesnt work when it integrate it with other application (which also works as a standalone ) I dont know which applications libraries to put first .

Comment: $(CC) -shared $(LFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) i used this and it worked. i think thats what you meant by linking dynamic lib . can you please tell why did it work this time ?